# How to retrieve and display data from Firebase onto a ListView?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have wandered YouTube and Stack Overflow in search of way to retrieve the **teacherName** value from the following database:

[image: Database]

I have not yet found a solution for my problem, whether I use a Value or ChildEventListener. This is the code I'm using:

```
public class ViewTeachersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Define the Teacher Firebase DatabaseReference
private DatabaseReference databaseTeachers;

// Define a String ArrayList for the teachers
private ArrayList<String> teachersList = new ArrayList<>();

// Define a ListView to display the data
private ListView listViewTeachers;

// Define an ArrayAdapter for the list
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

/**
 * onCreate method
 */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_teachers);

    // Associate the Teacher Firebase Database Reference with the database's teacher object
    databaseTeachers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseTeachers = databaseTeachers.child("teachers");

    // Associate the teachers' list with the corresponding ListView
    listViewTeachers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_teachers);

    // Set the ArrayAdapter to the ListView
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, teachersList);
    listViewTeachers.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    // Attach a ChildEventListener to the teacher database, so we can retrieve the teacher entries
    databaseTeachers.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            // Get the value from the DataSnapshot and add it to the teachers' list
            String teacher = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            teachersList.add(teacher);

            // Notify the ArrayAdapter that there was a change
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

I have also tried using a for loop inside the ChildEventListener, but that also didn't work. Can anyone point me to a solution?

Comment: Did you research before asking this? https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Comment: Specifically, this one. https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String teacher = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
```

You don't have a String there. You have an object.

So, you need a Java class

```
public class Teacher {
    String teacherID, teacherEmail; // etc. all fieldnames in the database

    public Teacher() {
    }

    // getters

    // setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.teacherID + ": " + this.teacherEmail;
    }
}
```

Then from Firebase, you can map the snapshot to that class and add to an adapter.

```
Teacher teacher = (Teacher) dataSnapshot.getValue(Teacher.class);
String teacherString = String.valueOf(teacher);
arrayAdapter.add(teacherString);
```

Refer: [Firebase-UI | Using Firebase to populate ListView](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-listview)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had tried to use the Teacher object earlier, but I was missing the toString() method in the Teacher class.

Comment: It's not necessary, but you'd see this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4#29140403

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is unclear if you want to listen for **all** teacherNames or just one.

This is an easy way to get all 'teacherName' for every entry (uuid key) under /teachers and adds a listener to this query:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReference()
    .child("teachers")
    .orderByChild("teacherName")
    .addValueEventListener(listener); //listener example below


ValueEventListener listener = new new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            dataSnapshot.getChildren().forEach(

               // assuming you are using RetroLambda, if not, implement Consumer<? super T> action
                // update change ListView here
            );
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError)
        {
            //handle errors here
        }
    });
```

If you are looking for getting a specific teacher name, comment and I'll change it. Also, I haven't tested syntax as I'm on mobile, so treat this as pseudocode but it should get you going in the right direction

Check out the Firebase Query [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#orderByChild(java.lang.String)), it is really straightforward and as of now can do really powerful stuff in a few lines of code. Be careful of outdated tutorials when searching, Firebase has added allot of its functionality in the last ~1 year

Comment: My purpose was to get every single teacher name. Sorry for being unclear. Thanks for your response!